# recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

When I try to run the android application it says "Unfortunately app has stopped". I have found that everything is fine up to `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` line(exclusive). I have read related articles but couldn't able to get any solution.  Here is `MainActivity.java`

```java
package com.newsapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.newsapp.api.ApiClient;
import com.newsapp.api.ApiInterface;
import com.newsapp.models.Article;
import com.newsapp.models.News;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String API_KEY = "ab6fad4399e24822a35c189dcde2eaa1";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    private Adapter adapter;
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        LoadJson();
    }

    public void LoadJson() {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        String country = Utils.getCountry();

        Call<News> call;
        call = apiInterface.getNews(country, API_KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<News>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getArticle() != null) {

                    if(!articles.isEmpty()) {

                        articles.clear();
                    }


                    articles = response.body().getArticle();
                    adapter = new Adapter(articles, MainActivity.this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Result!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here `Adapter.java`

```
package com.newsapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
import com.newsapp.models.Article;
import java.util.List;


public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Article> articles;
    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;


    public Adapter(List<Article> articles, Context context) {
        this.articles = articles;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view, onItemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holders, int position) {
        final MyViewHolder holder = holders;
        Article models = articles.get(position);

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.placeholder(Utils.getRandomDrawbleColor());
        requestOptions.error(Utils.getRandomDrawbleColor());
        requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
        requestOptions.centerCrop();

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(models.getUrlToImage())
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.title.setText(models.getTitle());
        holder.desc.setText(models.getDescription());
        holder.source.setText(models.getSource().getName());
        holder.time.setText(" \u2022 "+ Utils.DateToTimeFormat(models.getPublishedAt()));
        holder.published_ad.setText(Utils.DateFormat(models.getPublishedAt()));
        holder.author.setText(models.getAuthor());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener (OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView title, desc, author, published_ad, source, time;
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            published_ad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publishedAt);
            source = itemView.findViewById(R.id.source);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_load_photo);

            this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share more information? The full stack trace from the exception, or perhaps the adapter code?

Comment: please paste your adapter class

Comment: Adapter class added.

Comment: When an application fails look at the red logs. Show the logging information. Its easy to solve the problem after looking the logs.

Comment: please also add the error log from Logcat, when the app is dead

Comment: It maybe from an error in your layout(layout of your adapter). You must use logcat or use debug. If you trace error lines in some lines it says the main error. Also if you could start debugging in first of your adapter(Check for entering of your adapter and trace line by line).